# Trying to display image of tableView in circular form but its not showing it at the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   SublistTableViewCell *cell = [self.tvFestivalList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SublistTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell._img.layer.cornerRadius = cell._img.frame.size.width / 2;
   cell._img.clipsToBounds = YES;
   cell._img.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
   cell._img.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];


    return cell;
}
```

I am trying to display image of tableView in circular form but its not showing it at the first time. But when scroll the tableview image in cell are appearing in circular form

Comment: So where do you assign the image to the cell?

Comment: at cell for row at index path the problem is i am able to see the image at first time but not in circular for once i scroll down the cell is getting updated and then i can sell the imageView in circular form..i want the image in the circular form at first time as well.

Comment: You might want to set imageView properties in the `awakeFromNib` method of your `SublistTableViewCell`. Also you didn't say where you set the image to the cell.

Comment: i have set the image in the storyboard

Comment: You only have one image ? Can you show your SublistTableViewCell.h and SublistTableViewCell.m ?

Comment: now i am able to show the image in circular form, the problem was the height and width was not in square format